# How can I correctly pass state as props from one component to another?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to pass my state as props from component Locatione.js to Map.js, so the props are available when I call the function SendLocation in Map.js.

Here is my component Locatione

```
export default class Locatione extends Component {
  state = {
    location: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getLocationAsync();
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ });
    this.setState({ location });
    console.log("log this pls", this.state); // the state here logs correctly
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Map locatione={this.state} /> // when accesing this props in Map, I'm getting **null**
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my Map.js component

```
export default class Map extends React.Component {
  sendLocation() {
    console.log("sending location log", this.props); // the props here appear as null
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Send Sonar"
        onPress={(this.sendLocation, () => console.log("hi", this.props))} //the props here log correctly
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried passing my props in this fashion, to no avail.

```
export default class Map extends React.Component {

  sendLocation(altitude, longitude) {
    console.log("sending location log", this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Send Sonar"
        onPress={(this.sendLocation, (this.props)))}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little problem here:

```
        onPress={(this.sendLocation, () => console.log("hi", this.props))}
```

The console.log will trigger everytime the code renders or re-renders the button, not when you click it.

If you want to log after you call a function change the onPress to:

```
        onPress={() => {
                 this.sendLocation()
                 console.log("hi", this.props)
                }}
```

The other problem is that you are not giving your `sendLocation` function access to `this`.

You have two ways of doing it:

First way: Binding it inside your constructor. So inside your `Map.js` you add it like:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.sendLocation.bind(this);
}
```

Second way: Declaring your `sendLocation` function as an arrow function:

```
  sendLocation = () => {
    console.log("sending location log", this.props);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as you can pass regular values as props, you can also grab data from a component’s state and pass it down as props for any of its child components. You just need to pass the exact value, also use constructor in case of class components.

```
`export default class Location extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       location: null
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Map location={this.state.location} /> 
    );
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the function to `onPress` and use arrow function to be able to use `this` inside `sendLocation`.

```
class Map extends React.Component {

  sendLocation = () => {
    console.log('sending location log', this.props.locatione); // the props here appear as null
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Send Sonar"
        onPress={this.sendLocation}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you call the send location function as this way? It should trigger everytime the code renders ?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the props through components correctly, but you should use arrow function and also anonymous func.

Try:

```
export default class Map extends React.Component {

  sendLocation = (altitude, longitude) => {
    console.log("sending location log", this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Send Sonar"
        onPress={()=>this.sendLocation}
      />
    );
  }
}
```